# If/else front matter in Hexo

Tags: ejs, hexo

I have a markdown file in Hexo with the following in the front matter:

```
---
title: something blog post
tags:
  - local
  - world
categories:
  - news
date: 2016-07-27 15:08:51
twitter: twittername
facebook:
---
```

I have added two test variables (twitter and facebook) but is there a way to not output the content from the variable if the variable has not been set?

**This is what is outputted from the HTML:**

```
<ul id="social-links">
  <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/twittername" target="_blank">twittername</a></li>
  <li class="facebook"><a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Since the facebook variable was not filled you see nothing, this is breaking my layout since some posts will not have facebook or twitter and so on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with multiple if statements :

```html
<% if (page.twitter || page.facebook) { %>
  <ul id="social-links">
    <% if (page.twitter) { %>
      <li class="twitter">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/<%= page.twitter %>" target="_blank">
          <%= page.twitter %>
        </a>
      </li>
    <% } %>
    <% if (page.facebook) { %>
      <li class="facebook">
        <a href="http://facebook.com/<%= page.facebook %>" target="_blank">
          <%= page.facebook %>
        </a>
      </li>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
<% } %>
```